# Are encrypted strings URL Safe?

Tags: url, encryption

I have a need to encrypt a part of the URL e.g `https://www.example.com/resource/{resourceid}`.

The *resourceid* is the element that I want to encyrpt as it  *may be* a sensitive piece of information.

Before returning this URL to the clients, we want to encrypt the *resourceid* and on the way back (from the client on a subsequent request) we will decrypt the *resourceid* before processing.

The original *resourceid* is a string (alphanumeric characters). They are not super-secret, the intent is to make them an "opaque" string before returning them to the caller.

I am unable to figure out if the result of an encryption (symmetric key is what I am after) is URL safe? I can encrypt the resource ID and then do a URL encoding on top and do the reverse on the way back.

However, if the encryption outcome is already URL safe, i won't need to worry about it. I am unable to locate any information that states whether the outcome of an encryption function is URL safe or not.

Any help or pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Convert the binary encrypted data to URL-safe Base64, which replaces + and / with - and _ respectively.

Comment: That depends entirely on the particular encryption function used. The documentation for that function will tell you if it returns a urlsafe base64 string or not.